# Adding 'or' tags while filtering questions

Tags: support, tag-filters, custom-filters

While filtering questions by tags, you can add multiple tags. However, the questions are then filtered to those which contain *all* the tags I have mentioned. Is there a way I can filter questions to those that include *any* of the tags I have mentioned?

And if there isn't, it would be useful to have that feature. For example, I mostly use the physics stack exchange. I like to answer questions, but my knowledge is limited to specific areas and topics of physics. I want to create a custom filter which will show me all the questions about any of the fields I know, which currently I have to search seperately.

Comment: Please research before considering posting questions. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain this already works. I have this filter on SO:

[image: [bash] or [bash-completion] or [bash-trap] or [bash4] or [bash-on-windows] or [zsh] or [sh] or [awk]]

```
[bash] or [bash-completion] or [bash-trap] or [bash4] or [bash-on-windows] or [zsh] or [sh] or [awk]
```

And it works fine.